# read a line from a command out (stdout) to an array

Tags: ksh

I wrote such a script:

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh93

while read -A value; do
  print -- "I am here"
  print -- ${value[@]}
done < `<command>`
```

My intention is to redirect the stdout output of the `command` to populate the array. The above usage is inspired from this link: http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-scripting/66884-array-ksh-elems-containing-spaces.html, but it doesn't work in my case.

Anyone could tell me the cause of the failure?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Example command used is `ls -1` - with shell /bin/ksh. This stores output of the command in array.

```
ls -1 | { \
   n=0;
   set -A array
   while read line; do
        array[$n]=$line
        let n=$n+1
   done;
}

 # output commands here
    for l in ${array[@]}
    do
        echo $l
    done
```

Comment: Thank you. Still, I am confused why my code failed. It looks innocent.

Comment: Very helpful. I too would love more explanation of why your example works and why OP's code fails.